# Flashback table rows in SAP IQ 16.0

Tags: sql, oracle, sap-iq

My question is about "flashback" table in SAP IQ 16.0 .
Lets assume I have a table called tab_1 and I updated my table rows and committed accidentally. Is there a way to "flashback" table as we do in Oracle, I mean what is the alternative for flashback in SAP IQ?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IQ doesn't have flashback table -- But IQ has mvcc -- so I think -- maybe there's a workaround --

1. before you update the tab_1 -- open another connection (Connection B) on it -- and select some data on tab_1 -- **and don't run commit or rollback on it until the step 3 completed...**
2. update tab_1 on your working connection(Connection A) and accidently commited.
3. The tab_1 on conneciton B is still using the old version of tab_1 before Connection A's update-- so you can select * into tab_1_old_ver from tab_1 -- make a copy from this version on Connection B and commit.
4. Back to connection A-- drop the table tab_1 and commit and sp_iqrename tab_1_old_ver to tab_1

   And if your update is correct, then you can disconnect B after A's update completed.